# Xamarin.UITest: How to Determine If Xamarin.Forms.ListView Is Refreshing?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

In Xamarin.UITest, how can I determine if a `Xamarin.Forms.ListView` is refreshing?

When I perform `app.Query(x => x.Class("ListViewRenderer"))`, I get back only these results:

```
Query for Class("ListViewRenderer") gave 1 results.                             
[
   [0] {                                                                               
        Id => null,                                                                     
        Description => "md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ListViewRenderer{b749570 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1536}",                                                
        Rect => {                                                                           
            Width => 1080,                                                                  
            Height => 1536,                                                                 
            X => 0,                                                             
            Y => 240,
            CenterX => 540,
            CenterY => 1008
        },
        Label => null,
        Text => null,
        Class => "md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ListViewRenderer",
        Enabled => true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more information, I put together this blog post: https://codetraveler.io/2019/10/03/xamarin-uitest-determine-if-xamarin-forms-listview-is-refreshing/

**Android**

To interact with the ListView on Android from Xamarin.UITest, you must use the [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Invoke?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin) method to access the methods in the [native Java Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#isRefreshing()).

On Android, we can check the value returned from `SwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()` like so:

```cs
(bool)(app.Query(x => x.Class("ListViewRenderer_SwipeRefreshLayoutWithFixedNestedScrolling").Invoke("isRefreshing")).FirstOrDefault();
```

**iOS**

For iOS, we can check to see if the [`UIRefreshControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol) is visible:

```cs
app.Query(x => x.Class("UIRefreshControl")).Any()
```

### Code Sample

```cs
public bool GetIsRefreshIndicatorDisplayed(Xamarin.UITest.IApp app)
{
    if (app is AndroidApp)
        return (bool)(app.Query(x => x.Class("ListViewRenderer_SwipeRefreshLayoutWithFixedNestedScrolling")?.Invoke("isRefreshing"))?.FirstOrDefault() ?? false);

    if (app is iOSApp)
        return app.Query(x => x.Class("UIRefreshControl"))?.Any() ?? false;

    throw new NotSupportedException("Xamarin.UITest only supports Android and iOS");
}
```

### Sample App

Here is a sample app where I've successfully implemented this methodology: https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/blob/master/Src/UITestSampleApp.UITests/Pages/ListPage.cs